# changing attribute in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a structure as follows, and I want to change draggable attributes to false. 
    How can I do that in jquery? 
    Thanks.

```
<div id="top1">
    <span id="s1" draggable="True">a</span>
    <span id="s2" draggable="True">b</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

IF you want only, *TRUE* ones to be marked false

```
$("span[draggable='True']").attr('draggable', 'False');
```

Change attribute of all spans

```
$("span").attr('draggable', 'False');
```

Comment: If true and false are the only options, both of those have the same effect, since all spans will be set to false as a result. However, if there was a third option, then you're right.

Comment: @Anthony or else there are other `spans` used for different operations, you can't use the second code

Comment: I see what you had in mind. I thought you meant change all spans with draggable attribute versus all spans with draggable attribute set to false, which would be the same thing in the end.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#s1").attr("draggable", "False");
```

Answer (score 1):

its easy to do. You would loop over all the spans', then use 'attr' method of jquery to get the 'draggable' attribute and set it to false

```
    $("span").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("draggable")){
            $(this).attr("draggable","false");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Won't this add the attribute to spans not already having the `draggable` attribute?  And can't you use `attr()` to set the attribute for all selected elements at once, like: `$("span").attr("draggable","false");` instead of using the `each` loop?

Comment: I have updated my answer to make it false only if the current span has an attribute of 'draggable'.

Comment: But why use the `if` or the `each`? You can specify only `spans` of attribute `draggable` and set all of them to have the same value by using: `$("span[draggable]").attr("draggable","false");`  Just curious if you find using each more effective or faster.

Comment: @Anthony. I was not aware of that syntax. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the jquery documentation on [attributes](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), you can set an element's attribute using the `attr()` method. In your case:

```
$("#s2").attr("draggable", "False");
```

If you want to change all elements with the attribute `draggable` to false, you could use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) first, like so:

```
$('[draggable]').attr("draggable", "False");
```

Now, if you wanted to reverse the values, so that all currently true become false and all currently false become true, you have to store both sets into their own variable by using the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). Otherwise, you'd switch all to false, and wouldn't no which ones were already false to set to true. So something like:

```
var all_draggable =  $('[draggable="True"]');
var all_not_draggable =  $('[draggable="False"]');

all_draggable.attr("draggable", "False");
all_not_draggable.attr("draggable", "True");
```