# changing a link with javascript/jquery to an html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I am trying to add a twitter button to my website that will tweet out a quote, while normally the twitter link goes something like this:

```
      twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=what+is+happening?
```

by me the quote changes with each user click, i am trying to figure out to twit out the text inside a div/span/h5/p.

ive tried the following:

```
      $("a[href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=hello+world']").attr("href", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?="+h5)
```

it didnt change it at all

I'm a beginner if that makes a differnece ...

Comment: Where is `h5` defined? Your code should work unless its throwing an error...

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing attribute in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560211/changing-attribute-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this will work.  Note that the link will open in a new tab which appears to be blocked here on SO in the snippet but you can see it working [here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0gntxdn5/)

```js
$("img").click(function(){ 
  var arr = [
    'quote number 1',
    'quote number 2',
    'quote number 3',
    'quote number 4',
    'quote number 5',
    'quote number 6',
    'quote number 7',
    'quote number 8',
    'quote number 9',
    'quote number 10',
    'quote number 11',
    'quote number 12'
  ];
  
  var quote = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)]; // get random quote from the array
  $(".the-quote").html(quote); 
  var tweetUrl = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='+quote.replace(/s+/g, '+');
  $("#sendTweet").attr('href', tweetUrl);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click image to change quote<br>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"><br>
<div>
    <span>
        <h5>
            Current quote: <p class="the-quote">New Text to tweet</p>
        </h5>
    </span>
</div><br>
<a href="#" target="_blank" id="sendTweet">Click to Tweet</a>
```

Comment: actualy it only worked for the first quote, but after the user clicks and the quote changes the tweet is still the first quote

Comment: @nachal88 can you clarify? Im not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: I have an image on the site the every time its clicked the quote inside the h5 changes I use the following code for that: $("img").click(function(){
  $(".the-quote").html(arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * y)])
});   so when someone clicks the tweet button i want him to tweet the current quote

Comment: @nachal88 ok, check my edit, does that resolve the issue?

Comment: yes that works perfectly, thanks.  I'll be studying the new code now to understand it...